# what does idx * self.batch_size do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm pretty new to doing machine learning, and I stumbled upon Keras's [Sequence page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) and was trying to understand the code block here:

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
import math

# Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
# and `y_set` are the associated classes.

class CIFAR10Sequence(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        low = idx * self.batch_size
        # Cap upper bound at array length; the last batch may be smaller
        # if the total number of items is not a multiple of batch size.
        high = min(low + self.batch_size, len(self.x))
        batch_x = self.x[low:high]
        batch_y = self.y[low:high]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (200, 200))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

I got stuck at `__getitem__` and have no clue how `low` and `high` works, can anybody help explain to me what's happening in `__getitem__`? Why is `low = idx * self.batch_size`? Why is `high = min(low + self.batch_size, len(self.x))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `idx` represents the index, and the function `def __getitem__(self, idx):` is used to fetch data from your `CIFAR10Sequence` dataset. When loading data from a dataset, the dataloader generates the index (`idx`) to sample a batch of data.

Now, let's delve into the code within the `def __getitem__(self, idx):` function:

```
low = idx * self.batch_size
high = min(low + self.batch_size, len(self.x))
batch_x = self.x[low:high]
batch_y = self.y[low:high]
```

This function aims to sample a batch of data from your dataset within the interval defined by `low` and `high`. For example, suppose your dataset contains 420 data. If `idx = 42`, and the batch size `self.batch_size = 8`, the `def __getitem__(self, idx):` function will sample data from 42×8 to 42×8+8.

Now, let's see why the `min()` function is used. Consider another example: If `idx = 53`, 53×8 is greater than the total number of data (420). In this case, it would attempt to sample non-existent data. Therefore, through using `min(low + self.batch_size, len(self.x))`, this code ensures that the `def __getitem__(self, idx):` function does not sample data beyond the bounds of the dataset, preventing errors caused by trying to access non-existent data.